# Display the content from JQuery in a div tag with format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a simple web which runs a python program on a button click and displays the result in a div tag.
However it does not display the content line by line.

I checked the response in the browser:
Here's how to looks:

```
There are no Invalid Components

Wallet Information:
/te123i/oracle/admin/TE123I/wallet NOT_AVAILABLE

Displaying Central Inventory contents
Kindly Remove if there are any old entries of Oracle Home,
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
All rights reserved. -->
<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->
<INVENTORY>
<VERSION_INFO>
   <SAVED_WITH>12.1.0.2.0</SAVED_WITH>
   <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER>
</VERSION_INFO>
<HOME_LIST>
```

However it displays in the front end like this:( single line having entire output)

```
Checking for invalid components.... There are no Invalid Components Wallet Information: /te123i/oracle/admin/TE123I/wallet NOT_AVAILABLE Displaying Central Inventory contents Kindly Remove if there are any old entries of Oracle Home, <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> <!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. --> <!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. --> <INVENTORY> <VERSION_INFO> <SAVED_WITH>12.1.0.2.0</SAVED_WITH> <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER> </VERSION_INFO> <HOME_LIST>
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


    var b1 = $("#pre");



    var btnClick1 = function(e){
    alert("hey, you clicked RM button")
        $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'cgi-bin/test.py', //
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $('form').serialize(), // Send the form data in the request.
                success:function (result) {
                     $('#output').text(result);
                }
        });


    }


        b1.on('click', btnClick1);



    });
```

Is there anyway i can get the result displayed in the format just like the response?

update: The refrenced post was not the same. that had to do with php.

Comment: Put `<pre>` tags round the text

Comment: Thank you, it worked :))